# Where do I initialize log4net in XAML?

Tags: xaml, log4net

We are using log4net in an XAML app and we presently have a problem where we're getting an exception before log4net is ever initialized. Where is the very first code in an XAML app executed?

We're presently putting it in App.xaml.cs where App.xaml is:

```
<Application x:Class="Trebuchet.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" Startup="Application_Startup">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And the relevant App.xaml.cs is:

```
private static ILog log;

private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (App));
    log.Info(string.Format("Trebuchet version {0} started", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version));
    SetDevenvPaths();

    System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
}
```

Or are there other reasons that log4net can have trouble under xaml? For the case where this is occuring (on only one computer), I created a simple command line C# app and it creates a log file and writes to it fine. So it's something specific to this one app.

Update: And the app.exe.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821"/>
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">

      <param name="File" value="C:\Catapult.log"/>

      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
      <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="2"/>
      <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="100KB"/>
      <param name="RollingStyle" value="Size"/>
      <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] ac.server %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you are not configuring lognet by attribute in your assamblies:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

Then there is no need to put the Configure in your Application_Startup method.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Yes we also set it up in the app.exe.config file. I'll update.